# Comic about a (possibly) mutant soldier with a partner attempting to avoid a sniper/enemy

Tags: story-identification, comics, episode-identification

I was watching Clive Barker's *Nightbreed*, which stirred a memory I had of a comic I read when I was a child.

It seemed to be a compilation issue of a few comics, involving the first bit of *Akira*, a bit of the first *Nightbreed* comic involving [Dr. Decker/the button-faced mask guy](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/dr-decker/4005-58545/) and some other stories, including the one I'm trying to get figure out in this question.

Based on the age of those comics and my memory, I'd say around 1992/93 at the latest.

From memory:

1. There was at least one, potentially two soldier characters (partners) who I think were the protagonists; I have a feeling that they were mutants/not human (potentially blue), although they could have been just heavily covered up with equipment. I have a memory of some impressive visual aid/goggles. They are armed.
2. I think they were trying to evade being shot/killed by an unseen enemy.
3. The setting was a some kind of marshland/river with reeds, a reasonable amount of cover. I get the feeling it could have been a post nuclear war/disaster event world, which is why I think they were mutants.
4. I have a vague memory that one of them couldn't walk, maybe didn't even have legs, and he was strapped to the back of the other.
5. I think the more mobile character tries to make a break across the reeds, I have a memory of a panel where he's running, almost gazelle-like with the other guy strapped to his back. At this point, I think a bullet is fired and it either completely decapitates the guy he's carrying, or at least catches him in the head.
6. The whole comic dialogue has an air of humour to it, even when the chap is killed, I think his partner is more disappointed than upset.

I did wonder if it was a particular *Rogue Trooper* comic as that seems to fit the theme, but I'm not super familiar with the franchise and couldn't seem to pin down a specific issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this have been in the UK? I managed to turn up a Marvel UK anthology comic series called *[Meltdown](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/meltdown/4050-52272/)*, published in 1991–1992. It reprinted several stories including:

- *Akira*
- *Nightbreed*
- *The Light and Darkness War*
- *The Last American*

Out of the latter two stories, *The Last American* seems the most likely.

Comment: You are correct! I moved around a little bit when I was younger, so wasn't sure on the country of origin, it's issue #3 of Meltdown, the story/series is Cholly and Flytrap =D I'm going to post an answer with further details, but I'll accept this one as it put me on the right path.

Answer (score 5):

As [mkennedy correctly identified](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194528/104717), the comic series I'm thinking of is *[Meltdown](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/meltdown-3-meltdown-3/4000-367354/)*, specifically [issue #3](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/meltdown-3-meltdown-3/4000-367354/).

Within that issue there's as story about some characters called [Cholly and Flytrap](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3199517-the-original-adventures-of-cholly-and-flytrap).

[image: front cover of Meltdown #3]

The story I'm thinking of seems to be the first one in *The Original Adventures of Cholly and Flytrap*. I've been able to find it online and enjoy it all over again, my memory seemed to be broadly correct on most of the key points, with a few mix-ups. Notably, one guy is riding the other one, rather than being strapped to him/unable to move.

The comic is a great read, and very light hearted given the setting.

Bonus: Here is the panel I was describing as "gazelle-like":

[image: a panel from the comic, showing the scene described above]